# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars in simple python code

Tags: python, numpy

This is the python code

```
def arr_func(arr,selected_pixels_list): 

        rows = 2 
        m = 0 
        n = 0 
        i =0

        #Calculate the number of pixels selected 
        length_of_the_list = len(selected_pixels_list) 
        length_of_the_list = int(length_of_the_list/4)*4 
        cols = int(length_of_the_list/2) 
        result_arr = np.zeros((rows,cols)) 

        while(i<length_of_the_list): 
            result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]] 
            result_arr[m,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+1]] 
            result_arr[m+1,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+2]] 
            result_arr[m+1,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+3]] 

            i = i+4 
            m = 0 
            n = n+2 

        return result_arr 

import numpy as np

selected_pixel_data = np.load("coordinates.npy")
arr_data = np.load("arr.npy") 
response = arr_func(arr_data, selected_pixel_data)
print(response)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/work/sat/test_data.py", line 34, in <module>
    response = arr_func(arr_data, selected_pixel_data)
  File "d:/work/sat/test_data.py", line 16, in arr_func
    result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The data of loaded NumPy files

```
For selected_pixel_data:
shape = (597616, 2)
dtype = int32

For arr_data:
shape = (1064, 590)
dtype = float64
```

I have searched on the internet but it was mostly about MatLab and talking about vectorized
I have used .flatten()

```
response=arr_func(arr_data.flatten(),selected_pixel_data.flatten())
```

The errors are gone but is this the correct way?

Comment: Minor side-note: Instead of laboriously using a `while` loop to simulate a `for` loop, you could just do `from itertools import count` and write `for i in range(0, len(selected_pixels_list), 4):` with a first line of `n = i // 2` (or for likely faster, but uglier code, do `n_indices = range(0, len(selected_pixels_list), 2)`, then loop with `for i, n in zip(n_indices[::2], n_indices):` and you don't need to directly compute `i` or `n`). Also note: *Every* time you do `int(SOME_INT / DIVISOR)` you should be doing `SOME_INT // DIVISOR` instead (to do pure `int` math with floor division directly).

Comment: "Can anyone help me with what is wrong with the code?" Well, did you *read* the error message? Do you *understand* the error message? For example, see how the error message quotes your code `result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]]`? Did you understand that this is where the problem occurs? If you did: what do you think might be going wrong here? What do you think the result of `arr[selected_pixels_list[i]]` should look like? Did you check that? Does it work like you expect? Is that something that you think should be assignable to `result_arr[m,n]`? Why or why not?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. "can you send me the full code, please" Also please read [ask]. We don't work like that here.

Comment: I know the error come at result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]] I am not good at NumPy and new to this and can you explain if you know @KarlKnechtel

Comment: "I know the error come at result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]]" Well, *why* does the error appear there? What do you think `arr[selected_pixels_list[i]]` will do? For example, do you think the result should be an integer, or an array, or just what? Now, what does it *actually* do? Did you try to figure that out, for example by `print`ing the result?

Comment: "I am not good at NumPy and new to this and can you explain if you know" Again, we don't work that way. You would understand that if you read the links I gave you.

Comment: You should also try to explain, in plain English words, how you intend for the code to work, and what problem it is supposed to solve.

Comment: If I understand i never posted question here @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I don't think you understand, sorry.

Comment: Actually, this question is from my friend I debug the code with print statements and I google nothing worked so I raised the question here so that anyone helps me and points me in the correct way, and the result of arr[selected_pixels_list[I]] is a list of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the `shape` and `dtype` of `arr_data` and `selected_pixel_data`?  Tell us!  Rather than searching the web for "like sounding errors", focus on understanding your data.  If necessary, construct a simpler case.  The fact that your code is "simple" does not reduce the chance that you'll get an error!.

I can reproduce your error message with

```
In [14]: res = np.zeros((2,3))
In [15]: res[0,0] = np.arange(2)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [15] in <cell line: 1>
    res[0,0] = np.arange(2)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`res[0,0]` is the slot for one number.  `np.arange(2)` is 2 numbers, a "sequence".  Do you see the mismatch?

### edit

With `i,n,m` scalars and

```
shape = (597616, 2)
shape = (1064, 590)
```

single value slot: `result_arr[m,n]`

```
 selected_pixels_list[i] # (2,) shape
 arr[_]   # (2,590) shape
```

You can't put that 2d array in a single number slot.

You need to rethink the indexing and assignment.

### edit

What does the flattening do?

```
shape = (597616*2,)
shape = (1064*590,)
```

single value slot: `result_arr[m,n]`

```
 selected_pixels_list[i] # 1 element
 arr[_]   # 1 element
```

I works, but is that right?  What's the significance of the size 2 shape?  I suspect that is wrong

Another possibility is to interpret the 2 columns of `selected_pixels_list` as `i,j` indices of `arr`:

```
k, l = selected_pixels_list[i]   # 2 numbers
arr[k,l]   # 1 element
```

Comment: I have updated the shape and dtype can you check once

Comment: can i use .flatten() like 
response = arr_func(arr_data.flatten(), selected_pixel_data.flatten())
Errors are gone but i don't  know it is correct or not